# I can't write equations on my presentation

Tags: beamer, math-mode, errors, miktex

I am making a presentation on latex using the `beamer` document class. The preamble of my .tex file is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}%Paquete para poner dos columnas
\usepackage{pifont}
```

When I try to write equations in my presentation, I always obtain the following errors:

> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\equipo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\equipo\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log

When I do not write equations, everything works well, but every time that I try to use a mathematical environment like `$...$` or `\begin{equation}`, and I try to write something on it, it appears this error. Also, when I compile other kind of works, like a work using the book type, everything works well, even with equations. What is more strange is that I can write something like `$\rightarrow$, and there is no problem. But if I write something different, it appears the error. Actually, every time that I write a symbol like $\otimes$ everything if fine, but I can't write more complicated equations, just symbols.  :(

What is happening? Could anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: When did you install MikTeX and/or last run an update? Did you notice any error messages being issued relating to the installation/update?

Comment: Was the first `\usepackage{amssymb}` supposed to be `\usepackage{amsmath}`? You left that out but loaded `amssymb` twice (although I believe Beamer loads `amssymb` for you anyway).

Comment: Also, if you’re using `beamer`, you’re not submitting to a publisher or prof who still requires you to use PDFLaTeX in the 2020a. That means there is nothing stopping you from loading `unicode-math`, `fontsetup`, `newcomputermodern` or another modern font package in LuaLaTeX. That cuts a lot of Gordian knots in 8-bit font packages from last century.

Comment: And are you sure you really meant to use `[latin1]{inputenc}` instead of saving as UTF-8? Did you really mean to use all of those packages with Beamer? If you copied your preamble from some other template, I’d suggest you comment out all those packages and add back only the ones that you need to fix a bug.

Comment: I can’t duplicate your bug in TeX Live 2021. Cab you post a MWE that duplicates it and say which version of MikTeX you’re using? Are you sure all the packages you use are up to date?

Comment: Despite what I say above about the code in your document, this appears to be a problem with your MikTeX installation. You might be able to fix it by running the MikTeX console and making sure you’re up to date.

Comment: I use MacTeX2021, and I am also unable to replicate the issue you've reported above. Since it very much looks like your MikTeX installation is faulty, do please try the following: (a) uninstall MikTeX, followed by (b) re-install MikTeX from scratch. Make to follow this with a full update of all packages via the `mpm` (short for "MikTeX Package Manager") utility.

Comment: this is unrelated to the eror you show, but are you sure your document is in latin1 encoding not utf-8, you may want to delete `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`